# Creating floorplans with blender?

Tags: workflow

Are there any plans to add some basic floor plan features to create architectural plans? Some anotation tools, line styles and maybe a way to render straight on paper format would be amazing.

Comment: You are looking for a CAD tool. Try FreeCAD.

Answer (score 3):

Blender is a 3d creation tool. It already has everything you need to make any kind of graphics or architectural visualisations including [3d floor plans like this](https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-floor-plan-model-from-an-architectural-schematic-in-blender--cg-13350).

If you wish to work with 2d drawings, Blender can produce lines that can be exported as vector formats including dxf, it is also possible to import vector drawings to Blender and there are many modelling functions in Blender that can be used to work with 2d lines(curves or mesh edges). However it is not designed for this kind of work specifically and for this task you may want to use specially designed software because that might be easier. Special 2d CAD drawing software like ArchiCAD or Revit usually has templates, pre-made libraries of standard symbols, ways to print the drawings or save them to PDF and other useful functionality. It is possible to achieve that in Blender, however it will take a lot longer and will most likely be a lot more work if you only need 2d drawings.

There are some add-ons that aim to provide some functionality related to this. You might want to check [Blender-Archipack](https://blender-archipack.org/) out and search for more add-ons realated to architecture.

As for plans to make Blender into something that could be used for 2d architectural drawings specifically and would have all the expected functionality of 2d CAD software packages there does not seem to be any at Blender Foundation which is the main organisation developing Blender and it is probably unlikely there will ever be such plans as Blender is designed as specifically 3d creation tool and that is very unlikely to change. It is open source however, so there is nothing stopping anyone to take on such a task and make whatever they want from Blender, however there does not seem to be any serious projects like that at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just wondering this because blender has taken some steps towards 2d by introducing the 2d animation workflow in blender 2.80. But for now I definitely can get away by using CAD software like you mentioned.

Comment: I do use Blender to make line drawings and export them to ArchiCAD. I work with interior designers and sometimes it so happens that the visual design of some furniture gets done/modified on my end so it is often easy for me to just make the drawings out of 3d. Bisect operator is very useful: https://imgur.com/KcbmjkL I think it would be easy for me to make other drawings in Blender as well, but I have not tried it, however there are more tools for work with lines in CAD software and there are no *convenient* ways to print the drawings from Blender.

Comment: Some part of you answer is relevant but the rest, which you started defending blender, is absolutely uncessary. Blender is a 3d creation tool and mathematically and algebracilly speaking, 2d is a subspace of the 3d axis space. If blender doesn't offer this, it because of its poor imlementation, not that its focus is not on 2d, 1d or any of what you descirbed. In the end, it is what it is.

Comment: Actually, CAD 2d drawings is not the focus of Blender. It's not poor implementation, it's no implementation for most functions related to making CAD 2d drawings. Mathematically speaking 2d is a subset of 3d - you are right. We are not speaking mathematically, when we speak about working with 3d and then working with 2d drawings. There is a very clear distinction between software designed to do CAD and software dedicated to produce graphics. Blender was not designed to do CAD.